# Can't understand how this works

Tags: c, recursion

I don't understand this, as far as I understand this should goes like this;

4*4^2*4

but it doesn't, I know it has a simple explanation but still I tried to figure out this like for 20 minutes, I hope someone helps. Sorry for the bad editing too.

```
int power(int n1, int n2);

int main() {
    int base, powerRaised, result;

    printf("Enter base number: ");
    scanf("%d", &base);

    printf("Enter power number(positive integer): ");
    scanf("%d", &powerRaised);

    result = power(base, powerRaised);

    printf("%d^%d = %d", base, powerRaised, result);
    return 0;
}

int power(int base, int powerRaised) {
    if (powerRaised != 0)
        return (base * power(base, powerRaised - 1));
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: The C language does not have an exponentiation operator. ^ is bitwise XOR.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker that was just pseudo code to you understand not c code obviously

Comment: The code seems to work. What is you precise problem?

Comment: power function  does not calculate 4^2 just decrements 1 l and starts calculating

Comment: add printf("entering power(%d,%d)\n",base,powerRaise); at the start of your power function and you will see what happens.

Comment: what about [powerRaised - 1]  it's like it's not there

Comment: Post the _exact_ input used, output seen, output expected.  Hopefully input was not "4*4^2*4"`.

Comment: What do you think that line is doing? It seems like you should understand the concept of recursion if that's one of the tags you added.

Comment: It might also help you to learn how to debug, and step through a program line by line (including stepping into function calls and examining variables/arguments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code behaves as expected, the `power` function is recursive. For arguments `4` and `2`, it calls itself recursively twice:

```
   power(4, 2)
-> 4 * power(4, 1)
-> 4 * (4 * power(4, 0))
-> 4 * (4 * 1)
-> 16
```

You might be more familiar with an iterative approach:

```
int power(int base, int powerRaised) {
    int res = 1;
    while (powerRaised > 0) {
        res = res * base;
        powerRaised--;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: but why it does not calculate 4^2 just decrements  1 l and starts calculating

Comment: @muhammedkartal Exponentiation is, at the lowest level, not a single-step operation and C does not hide that from you

Comment: i get it with while but this recursion is just killing me thanks for everything